# In JavaScript, is there a way to enumerate all private properties of an object?

Tags: javascript, private-members

In the following code:

```js
class Foo {
  #a;
  #b = 123;
  c = 3.14;

  tellYourself() {
    console.log("OK the values are", JSON.stringify(this));
  }
}

const foo = new Foo();

foo.tellYourself();
```

Only this is printed:

```
OK the values are {"c":3.14}
```

Is there a way to print out all properties automatically, including the private ones?

(meaning if there are 25 private variables, print all of them out automatically, instead of specifying them one by one?).

Comment: Could you specify the purpose of this? Probably you should use another instruments to achieve your goal.

Comment: @Yogi that answer is that, it is not possible? How authoritative is it?

Comment: @RomanLytvynov if it is only for debugging. I mean, to the object, these are private values that I have. "If I feel like it", I should be able to use a simple statement to print them all out

Comment: @StefanieGauss for debugging purposes it is better to use debugger tools. For the production purposes you should redesign your solution. Unfortunately I can not suggest you more concrete solution, because I do not know all your requirenments. Just keep in mind, that you can not enumerate private properties.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible.

> The only way to access a private property is via dot notation, and you can only do so within the class that defines the private property.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_properties

So I can suggest you to redesign your solution according to your goal.

Comment: Well, it's not *impossible*, the OP could write code to explicitly print out each of the private properties. However you are correct in that it cannot be done any other way.

Comment: Thats the point, that you can`t iterate the private properties. So it is not possible to do exact what was asked - stringify or print all properties, including private, without pointing them directly.

Comment: Yes exactly, upvoted :)

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, you can extract private props from the class definition:

```js
class Foo {
  #a;
  #b = 123;
  c = 3.14;

  tellYourself() {
    const props = Foo.toString().match(/(?<=^\s*#)[^ =;]+/gm);
    const priv = eval(`({${props.map(prop => `'#${prop}': this.#${prop}`).join(',')}})`);
    
    console.log("OK the values are", {...this, ...priv});
  }
}

const foo = new Foo();

foo.tellYourself();
```

Comment: Requiring the `#` to come as the first non-whitespace character in a line won't work on minified code and some unusual coding styles. Also you always may get false positive matches, so I would recommend to `props.filter(p => eval(`#${p} in this`))` and also wrap the whole thing (or even each individual field) in `try`/`catch`

Comment: @Bergi yes, the example could be elaborated, but as mentioned i didnt expect it taken seriously